# Can I find where a NullPointerException came from?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

When I'm trying the following statement,

```
a.do(b.do());
```

suppose I got a NullPointerException from that line.

then, is there any way to find whether a is null of b is null?

Comment: simple solution is explicit Check has to made to a and b before this statement

Comment: a.do(b.do != null ? b.do : new b().do).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the only solution is to extract the inner expression:

```
Object o = b.do()
a.do(o);
```

Which is a good idea anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you debug your program in eclispe or any standard IDE you can do `Step Into` which will first execute `b.do()`. If it crashes your problem is with the `b` object. If not `Step Out` from `b.do()` and `Step Into` `a.do()` and find your problem there.

I must say though Tomasz's approach is much safer and recommended to use as it is also readable.

Comment: +1 In a debugger in any IDE, you should be able to see the values of `a` and `b` before attempting to step into the line to see which is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Either a or b is null for that statement to cause an error. You cannot see which, except by checking each object seperately.

Also, isn't "do" a reserved keyword? Not sure.